# SVN Getting version

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to extract folder from SVN which is specific date. I am using the TortoiseSVN client where for specific folder version i only get 20 days back. Not more than that. Is there any way we can get version which was like 2 months back? I have not tagged the code. But i know need to get the version only specific to two months back.

Please let me knwo if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Tortoise Log Browser (context menu, "Tortoise SVN/Show Log") you can click on the bottom left button "Show All" to see all versions instead of the latest 100. Just to the right is the button "Next 100" if you don't want to load all log messages.

After you have found the revision you are looking for, you can use the Tortoise Repository Browser and click on the top right button "HEAD". There you can enter the revision number and then check out the directory you are looking for with that revision.

Answer (score 2):

At least on my copy of Tortoise SVN, on the Checkout dialog, there is a section at the bottom for selecting a Revision. Instead of using `HEAD revision`, select `Revision` and press the "Show Log" button. You can then use the date selectors (From and To) to narrow down the range of displayed revisions. Scroll through the list of commits until you find the revision that you want, select it and press OK.